# c++ createprocess powershell as admin, hidden and dont wait for it

Tags: c++, powershell

This is what I have, starting powershell.exe without the command and closing directly after it.
why doesnt it work?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

[...]
CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
    "powershell.exe -command \".C:\\test\\t.ps1\"   ",      
[...]
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi );          // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure

return 0;
}
```

in normal cmd the command would look like this:

```
powershell -command ".c:\test\t.ps1"
```

and in the file this one-liner, if you want to test it:

```
write-host "hello world" |out-file C:\test\hi.txt
```

should write hello world in the console and create hi.txt in the folder

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: it starts powershell but not the script. like opening cmd and not executing the batch file

Comment: `".c:\test\t.ps1"` is not correct syntax. Type that command at a PowerShell prompt and you can see this for yourself. I think you mean `-file "C:\test\t.ps1"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command line should be either:

```
CreateProcess(NULL, // No module name (use command line)
    "powershell.exe -command \"& {C:\\test\\t.ps1}\"",
```

or

```
CreateProcess(NULL, // No module name (use command line)
    "powershell.exe -file C:\\test\\t.ps1",
```

In general, for executing scripts use -File unless the exit code is important to you.  If it is, use `-Command` because there is a bug with -File where it always returns 0 (success) even if there is an error.

If you want the execution of powershell.exe to prompt for elevation, use the [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) API instead.  Pass in `"RunAs"` for `lpOperation` and you can specify a hidden window with the `nShowCmd` parameter.

Comment: k thx. how can i let it ask for admin rights if i dont have them already?

Comment: What do you do in case the file name or folder path contains `}` in the first example?